# displaying data as a line in charts

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')
df$countryName = as.character(df$countryName)
```

I processed the dataset.

Can we show the patient and population charts of the continents as separate line charts on the same chart?

as output;

''date         region    confirmed
''2020/01/03   europa     850

The data in the output I created are examples. The data in the example are not real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `ggplot`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  group_by(region, day) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(confirmed = sum(confirmed),
            recovered = sum(recovered),
            death = sum(death)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("confirmed","recovered","death"), names_to = "condition") %>%
ggplot(aes(x= as.Date(day), y = value, group = region, color = region)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(rows = vars(condition), scales = "free_y") + 
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Number of Individuals")
```

[image]